Why the sync function is behaving like async function and vice-versa?
I'm trying to understand the difference between sync and async functions using Python fast API. In the following code, I have written a sync function and put a 10-second time delay in it. When I try to call this API two times simultaneously, I get the response time to the two calls is the same (10sec).  For example, I called this API the first time and again called this API after 3 seconds. Usually, the first request will take a time of 10.2sec and the second request will take 13.2 sec, but both requests have the same response time (it is around 10.2 sec).
from fastapi import FastAPI
import time
import random
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def roots(req_id):
    print("Waiting for Sleep by", req_id)
    time.sleep(10) # 10 sec user1 - block  - concurrency -async
    print("Sleep completed for ", req_id)
    return "Hello"



# Sync func  -> sequential, blocking

The fascinating thing which confuses me more is, that if I put an async keyword in front of the function, it's the two responses have different times. Somebody, please explain to me why these two scenarios have different time frames and moreover, why sync API is behaving like async and vice-versa

Fast API is probably multithreaded, so different threads are given each request. time.sleep only blocks the current thread.

Yes, that seems to be the case: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions. "When you declare a path operation function with normal def instead of async def, it is run in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server)."

In the async endpoint change time.sleep(10) to await asyncio.sleep(10). time.sleep() blocks event loop and second request can not be handled
